# Microservice pattern with shared microservice

Tags: microservices

Let's say I have an application where I use multiple microservices. Two of them are *USERS* ( /users ) and *CARS* ( /cars ).
Given a page called rental history ( /users/{id}/history ) which lists the rented car of the users.

Should I introduce an intermediary microservice *RENTAL* ( /rental ) which would query the other two microservices for the best architectural design ?

What is the correct design if I wanted to deploy this app under different brands, which means *USERS* database would be different , but the *CARS* database would be shared between the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you have a rental microservice to coordinate the process of renting (and returning etc.) a car by a user.  Then the logic only appears in the rental service, not spread out over however many other services (counting UIs and such as services for this purpose).

I would actually question whether different brands would need fully-different user services, because there'd be a lot of common functionality.  It might make sense to have a general user service with brand namespaces user IDs (so that, for instance, the rental service doesn't need to know about brands) and some brand-specific facades (e.g. to add the namespace to the IDs and maybe even handle things like frequent renter programs).

Comment: Thank you. So basicly the best strategy would be to have one database, and one of each microservice, and add a discriminator column in *USERS* table for brands ? If I wanted to do some statistics, like rental count by brands, which would use the *RENTAL* microservice, am I allowed to do read-only operations by joining the tables(user-rental), or is it better practice to propagate the discriminator column to the *RENTAL* table ?

Comment: I'd recommend out of those options that if the rental service needs to know (e.g. for analytics) the brand associated with a user, it should be in a table owned by the rental service without being joined. (I do strongly lean toward no 2 microservice sharing anything you can query: that precludes a reliable join between users and rentals). I would consider, though, encoding the brand into the user id (e.g. `brand:userid`) at least for anything touching the user service directly.